# Getting authentication exception while authenticating against LDAP using spring 4.0 security:

Tags: exception, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Getting following authentication exception while authenticating against `LDAP` using `spring 4.0` security:

Following is full stack trace of this issue :

```
 org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191)      at 
org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:355)
                    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:139)
                    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getContext(AbstractContextSource.java:130)
                    at com.globalpay.bvlogin.security.ldap.service.impl.BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.java:95)
                    at com.globalpay.bvlogin.security.ldap.service.impl.BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.bindWithDn(BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.java:81)
                    at com.globalpay.bvlogin.security.ldap.service.impl.BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.authenticate(BvLoginCustomBindAuthenticator.java:61)
                    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187)
                    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
                    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
                    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
                    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
                    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
                    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:134)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
                    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
                    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
                    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
                    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3136)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3082)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
                    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
                    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
                    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
                    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
                    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42)
                    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:343)
                    ... 45 more


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Following is the configuration in spring-sec-config.xml file:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"    access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/?error" login-processing-url="/performLogin"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />

        <!-- <security:logout logout-success-url="/login" /> -->

        <security:session-management
            session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/performLogout">
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </security:session-management>

        <security:csrf />

        <security:headers>
            <security:cache-control />
            <security:content-type-options />
            <security:xss-protection />
            <security:frame-options />
            <security:hsts />
        </security:headers>

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="ldapAuthManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
         <constructor-arg
            value="ldaps://company.team.san.com:636/DC=team,DC=san,DC=com" />                   
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=service_crs,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Administration,DC=team,DC=san,DC=com" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.adminUserPassword}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="bindAuthenticator" />     
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="ou=ExternalUsers" />
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean           
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator"
        id="bindAuthenticator">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <!-- <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" /> -->
        <property name="userDnPatterns">
            <list>
                <value>uid={0},OU=ExternalUsers</value>                 
                <!-- <value>uid={0},ou=Administration</value> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!--     <security:ldap-server ldif="classpath:users.ldif"  root="dc=san,dc=org"/> -->

</beans>
```

---

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your code? Did it work in the past? Please provide more details.

Comment: I have provided above configuration code to authenticate user using Spring Ldap authentication. But whenever I login to application it throws above error.

Answer (score 0):

```
LDAP: error code 49
```

means 'invalid credentials', sometimes this error code is also returned (for security reasons) when the entry/account is locked

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but user account is active still I am facing this issue.. :(

Comment: The first test is to use ldapsearch tool to verify the credentials are valid, this is independent from account status.